# R apply function on data frame column

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I need to , efficiently, parse one of my dataframe column (a url string)
and call a function (strsplit) to parse it, e.g.:

```
url <- c("www.google.com/nir1/nir2/nir3/index.asp")

unlist(strsplit(url,"/"))
```

My data frame : spark.data.url.clean looks like this:

```
                    classes              url
 [107,662,685,508,111,654,509] drudgereport.com/level1/level2/level3
```

This df has 100k rows and I don't want to loop/iterate over it, parse each url separately and write the results to a new data frame.
What I DO need/want is to create a new 5 column data frame:

```
df.result <- data.frame(fullurl = as.character(),baseurl=as.character(), firstlevel = as.character(), secondlevel=as.character(),thirdlevel=as.character(),classificaiton=as.character())
```

call one of the "apply" family function over `spark.data.url.clean$url`
and to write the results to the new data frame `df.result` such that the first column (`fullurl`) will be populated with the relevant `spark.data.url.clean$url`, the 2nd to 5th columns will be populated with the relevant results from applying

```
unlist(strsplit(url,"/"))
```

- taking the only the first, 2nd, 3rd and 4th elements from the resulted vector and putting it in the first,2nd, 3rd and 4th columns in `df.result` and finally putting the `spark.data.url.clean$classes` in the new data frame columns `df.result$classificaiton`

Sorry for the complication and let me know if anything need to be further cleared out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for `apply`, as far as I see it.

Try this:

```
spark.data.url.clean <- data.frame(classes = c(107,662,685,508,111,654,509), 
  url = c("drudgereport.com/level1/level2/level3", "drudgeddddreport.com/levelfe1/lefvel2/leveel3", 
          "drudgeaasreport2.com/lefvel13/lffvel244/fel223", "otherurl.com/level1/second/level3", 
          "whateversite.com/level13/level244/level223", "esportsnow.com/first/level2/level3", 
          "reeport2.com/level13/level244/third"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df.result <- spark.data.url.clean

names(df.result) <- c("classification", "fullurl")

df.result[c("baseurl", "firstlevel", "secondlevel", "thirdlevel")] <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(df.result$fullurl, "/"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using the package `splitstackshape` to do this; we can use its `cSplit`-function. Setting `drop` to `F` ensures that the original column is preserved. Not that it returns a `data.table`, not a `data.frame`.

```
library(splitstackshape)
output <- cSplit(dat,2,sep="/", drop=F)
```

data used:

```
dat <- data.frame(classes="[107,662,685,508,111,654,509]",
                  url="drudgereport.com/level1/level2/level3")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option with `data.table` which should be pretty fast. If your data looks like this:

```
> df
#                        classes                                   url
#1 [107,662,685,508,111,654,509] drudgereport.com/level1/level2/level3
```

You can do the following:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)  # convert to data.table 
cols <- c("baseurl", "firstlevel", "secondlevel", "thirdlevel") # define new column names
df[, (cols) := tstrsplit(url, "/", fixed = TRUE)[1:4]]  # assign new columns
```

Now, the data looks like this:

```
> df
#                         classes                                   url          baseurl firstlevel secondlevel thirdlevel
#1: [107,662,685,508,111,654,509] drudgereport.com/level1/level2/level3 drudgereport.com     level1      level2     level3
```

Answer (score -1):

The simple solution is to use:

```
apply(row, 2, function(col) {})
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.